# Grakn rule that matches on a super-relation failing to find matching instance of its subrelation

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have a Grakn schema fragment for modelling an in-game 'research tree' that looks like this:

```
# Entities
research-project sub entity,
    has name,
    plays research-task,
    plays required-tech,
    plays research-to-begin;

campaign sub entity,
    has name,
    plays campaign-with-tasks;

# Relations
requirement sub relation,
    abstract,
    relates prerequisite,
    relates outcome,
    plays task;

tech-requirement sub requirement,
    abstract,
    relates required-tech as prerequisite,
    relates outcome;

tech-requirement-to-begin-task sub tech-requirement,
    abstract,
    relates required-tech as prerequisite,
    relates task-to-begin as outcome;

tech-requirement-to-begin-research sub tech-requirement-to-begin-task,
    relates required-tech as prerequisite,
    relates research-to-begin as outcome;

campaign-task sub relation,
    abstract,
    relates campaign-with-tasks,
    relates task,
    has started,
    has progress,
    has can-proceed,
    has completed;

campaign-research-task sub campaign-task,
    relates campaign-with-tasks,
    relates research-task as task;
```

The property `can-proceed` of `campaign-task` is governed by a set of rules, one of which is the following:

```
when {
    $campaign isa campaign;
    $campaign_task($campaign, task: $task) isa campaign-task, has completed false;
    not {
        (task-to-begin: $task, required-tech: $prerequisite) isa tech-requirement-to-begin-task;
        ($campaign, $prerequisite) isa campaign-task, has completed false;
    };
}, then {
    $campaign_task has can-proceed true;
};
```

Each prerequisite is modelled using a `tech-requirement-to-begin-research` relation, which is a subrelation of the abstract `tech-requirement-to-begin-task`.

**Expected outcome:** it should mark a campaign-task as having `can-proceed = true` *only if* it has NO prerequisite campaign-tasks that are not completed.

**Actual outcome:** it does not detect the `tech-requirement-to-begin-research` instances, and simply marks all campaign-tasks with `can-proceed = true`, even if they have unfulfilled prerequisites.

If I change the rule by replacing `task-to-begin` with `research-to-begin`, AND `tech-requirement-to-begin-task` with `tech-requirement-to-begin-research`, then the rule correctly applies only to tasks that have no unmet prerequisites. However, doing so loses generality, and will require rewriting the rule for every subrelation of `tech-requirement-to-begin-task`, resulting in a lot of code duplication.

What is the expected behaviour in this case and what is the best way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your expected outcome is correct - the rule should apply the negation over `tech-requirement-to-begin-task` and its subtypes (including `tech-requirement-to-begin-research`). Therefore, the best way to resolve this is to open an issue on the Grakn repo and have this behaviour fixed in Grakn's reasoner!